# valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown' for input type="numeric" in Knockoutjs 2.0

Tags: input, numbers, knockout.js

[see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedbd/hY5T2/) for illustration]

I set up a value bind to an `input` of type number, and want the bound `observable` to immediately reflect changes to the value of the field. to do that I set the `afterkeydown` valueUpdate binding. This works well for changing the number input using the arrow up and arrow down keys. However, if I change the number using the browser-generated (tested in chrome) increment/decrement control the change is only reflected upon changing focus to a different element. I assume this reflects the default update upon change event.

My question is whether there is any way to set the update to occur for both changes using the up down keyboard errors and browser-generated up/down error controls?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `valueUpdate` additional binding can take an array of events.  It looks like the `oninput` event is fired when clicking on the up/down arrows.

So, you can bind it like:

`<input type="number" data-bind="value: y, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown', 'input']"/>`

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/hY5T2/9/

Comment: Using this in my MVVM DotNetNuke module I get tiny (!) spinner-up and spinner-down buttons. They are so small it´s almost impossible to use them. I recon it´s a CSS-thing, but haven´t been able to figure it out. If I instead of the <input type="number" data-bind="value: y, valueUpdate:…"> go with <input data-bind="spinner: y, valueUpdate:…"> every thing looks nice, but the valueUpdate does´t work… 
Things that make you go hmm...

Comment: Had an issue with Selenium test scripts not updating observables, and this resolved it for me.